# Extending a field homomorphism on a finite field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $a,b,c$ be positive integers, $a$ divides $b$ and $b$ divides $c$.

Fix homomorphisms $f\colon\mathbb{F}_{p^{a}}\to\mathbb{F}_{p^{b}}$ and $g\colon\mathbb{F}_{p^{a}}\to\mathbb{F}_{p^{c}}$.

I want to show that there is a field homomorphism $h\colon\mathbb{F}_{p^{b}}\to\mathbb{F}_{p^{c}}$ such that $h\circ f=g$.

I don't want to use the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ (my question arises from trying to understand the construction of this algebraic closure via direct limits).

Comment: Do you know that $g$ extends to a homomorphism $\mathbb{F}_{p^b}\to\mathbb{F}_{p^c}$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I don't know that. Extends in what sense? By looking at $\mathbb{F}_{p^a}$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{p^b}$ via $f$?

Comment: If you use $f$ then the extension is exactly what you are asking about. Do you not know any theorems about extending morphisms to field extensions?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: The theorems that I know discuss the situation where the range is algebraically closed. If you can state the general useful theorem that can help me here, I'll appreciate it. Even with no proof and no reference it will be useful.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: If you do state such a theorem, it will be useful to state a general one. One thing I am confused about is what is special about the finite field situation and what is general.

Comment: The standard one is: Let $E$ be a field, $p(x)$ an irreducible polynomial with coefficients in $E$, and let $F$ be an extension of $E$ with $F=E(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x)$. If $\sigma\colon E\to K$ is a field homomorphism such that $\sigma(p)$ has a root $\beta$ in $K$,then there exists a homomorphism $\tau\colon F\to K$ such that $\tau(\alpha)=\beta$ and $\tau|_{E} = \sigma$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: OK. I proved the theorem you stated. Now I will think how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K,L,M$ be three finite fields with two homomorphisms

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K @>{\alpha}>> M \hookrightarrow L \\
@V{\beta}VV \\
L
\end{CD}$$

We need to find a homomorphism $\gamma : M \to L$ that makes the triangle commutative. It suffices to find a homomorphism $L \to L$ with that property (because this can then be restricted to $L$). So the task simplifies to completing diagrams of the form

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K @>{\alpha}>> L  \\
@V{\beta}VV \\
L
\end{CD}$$
to a homomorphism $\gamma : L \to L$ with $\gamma \circ \alpha = \beta$. In fact, $\gamma$ will be an automorphism.

Notice that $\mathrm{im}(\alpha)$ and $\mathrm{im}(\beta)$ are two subfields of $L$ with the same order. Hence, they are equal. In fact, if $K$ has order $q$ and $L$ has order $q^m$, then $L$ has a unique subfield of order $q$, namely $\{x \in L : x^q = x\}$.

It follows that there is some automorphism $\pi : K \to K$ with $\beta = \alpha \circ \pi$ (we define $\pi$ by $\beta(x) = \alpha(\pi(x))$, it exists since $\beta(x) \in \mathrm{im}(\alpha)$ etc.). So we can completely remove $\beta$ from the task, we only need to find $\gamma$ with $\gamma \circ \alpha = \alpha \circ \pi$.

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K @>{\alpha}>> L  \\
@V{\pi}VV @VV{\gamma}V \\
K @>>{\alpha}> L
\end{CD}$$

This can be proven in at least two ways. One proof uses that $\alpha : K \to L$ is a normal extension. Another proof just uses that we actually know all the automorphisms of $K$, they are all powers of the Frobenius $x \mapsto x^p$, where $p = \mathrm{char}(K)$. On $L$, we can then take the same power of the Frobenius, and that's it.